# History.js - detect state when directly accessed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

I'm trying to figure out `History.js`, the following code works if you go to `index.html` but if you try to access `index.html?info` directly, it displays the index content. How exactly are you supposed to detect state when somebody tries to directly access `index.html?info`? Also, I'm not sure if I'm doing the initial state properly either.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.history.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content"></div>

    <script>
        History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
            var id = History.getState().data.id;

            if (id == "index") {
                $('#content').html('<button id="btn" type="button">get info</button>');
                $('#btn').click(function() {
                   History.pushState({ id: "info" }, '', '?info'); 
                });
            }

            if (id == "info") {
                $('#content').html('here is some info');
            }
        });

        History.pushState({ id: "index" }, '', '?index'); //do this otherwise nothing loads on first run
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are always pushing the index state in your example. What you could do is something like this: Instead of History.pushState write:

```
var p = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" ); //this gets you the parameter
History.replaceState({id: p}, '', '?'+p);
```

However, History state is preserved on refresh and as such on refreshing the page the statechange event will not fire, since the state doesn't change.

So to go around this you would need something like this:

```
var historyFired = false;

function onHistory() {
  //put code previously in your statechange hanlder here
  historyFired = true;
}

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',onHistory);

var p = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" ); //this gets you the parameter
History.replaceState({id: p}, '', '?'+p);

if (!historyFired) onHistory();
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it does what you want it to do;

Comment: Ok, that works when directly accessing index.html?info then. But if you refresh the page, it will be blank again, even though ?info is in the url. I feel like something still isn't right.

Comment: Yeah you're right. It doesn't work on refresh. You can use pushState instead of replace and see if it works. Although that will screw around if the user preess the  Back button right away.

Comment: pushState doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: OK, the state is preserved upon refresh, I didn't know what. I updated my answer to account for that.